# Youtube player API and jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-javascript-api

I am using the YouTube API to get the current elapsed time of a video: `player.getCurrentTime();`  and the `player.getDuration();` functions; I have set a slider in jQuery that will have the max value set to `player.getDuration` and the min to 0;

Using those two functions I have built the following piece of code:

```
    var progress = setInterval(function(){
       $("#progressbar").slider({value: Math.floor(player.getCurrentTime())}); 
    },1000);
```

that will update a slider with the elapsed time of the Youtube video. 
The problem is that when I pause the video, the value of the slider flickers between an earlier value, and the current elapsed time (`player.getCurrentTime()`) value.

Can someone explain?

**EDIT:** here is the proper code that updates the slider on player play state and stops the update function on player pause state:

```
    function playerStateChange(newState) {
     globalYtState = newState;
     if(newState == 0){
   $("#hSongSearcher").val('').trigger('keyup');
   setTimeout(playNextVideo(),1500);
     }
     if(newState == 2){
     clearInterval(progressUpdater);
     }
     if(newState == 1){
    progressUpdater = setInterval(function(){
     //console.log(Math.floor(player.getCurrentTime()));
    if(Math.floor($("#progressbar").slider('value')) != Math.floor(player.getCurrentTime())){
        $("#progressbar").slider({value: Math.floor(player.getCurrentTime())});
    }
                     $('.current_elapsed').html(getPropperDuration(Math.floor(player.getCurrentTime())));
            },1000);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, this may help anyone else. I have found out that when running this piece of code:

```
    $("progressbar").on('slidechange',function(event,ui) { ...
```

it seems that the ui.value flickers in my example between the current getCurrentTime() value and a maybe random value? ( I don't know exactly from where that value is! but I know a good workaround that will fix that);

SO I have made a var that holds the player current time on each second, and just pass by that random flickering value of the slider as follows:

```
    if(newState == 1){
progressUpdater = setInterval(function(){
    ctime = Math.floor(player.getCurrentTime());
    $("#progressbar").slider("value", ctime);
    //Here starts the flickering fix
    $("#progressbar").on('slidechange',function(event,ui){
        //Fix Flcikering;
        if(ui.value < ctime){
            $("#progressbar").slider("value", ctime);
        }
    });
    //And here it ends.
    $('.current_elapsed').html(getPropperDuration(Math.floor(player.getCurrentTime())));
    },1000);
  }
```

Comment: Meh. Bad decision dough. I have made a new way of getting that progress bar better. I will update the code later today.